# Can not Start Process on certain PC

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, .net-4.7

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "web.whatsapp.com --new-window --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=\"Chrome Profile\"";
proc.Start();
```

The above code opens Chrome just fine in my PC. But I copied it to a client and the Chrome didn't opened. I cross checked chrome location, ran as administrator but for no help.

What might be the problem? I tried the above command in CMD on the client side and the chrome opened as expected. Then why can't C# open it?

Can this be anti-virus issue? (I didn't got a chance to disable anti-virus.)

Comment: Did you try after pausing the AV?

Comment: Do you get any errors/exceptions, or does it just do nothing?

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup I got that thought after meeting was over. I will meet him after 2 days.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb no error, just like it has forgot to do that step.

Comment: Process class will look for any files in same folder as the c# executable. When files are in a different folder you need the path.  The following may be an issue : web.whatsapp.com

Comment: @jdweng it is the name of website. This argument tells to open this site.

Comment: Try use "/C " before web.whatsapp.com in arguments.

Comment: @SilnyToJa any kind of explanation?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta /C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates. I dont sure it help for your problem, but it was solution for my similar.

Comment: @SilnyToJa Ok noted. But even if the arguments are wrong, chrome still opens in normal circumstances.

Comment: Make sure you project settings are x86.

Comment: What error you got or did you get any exceptions?? Maybe client's desktop is 32 bit so there is no 'Program Files (x86)' folder or maybe there is an anti-virus issue which anti-virus software you use?

Comment: @jdweng Project is set to Any CPU, .NET 4.7

Comment: @TusharChaurasia I have mentioned in question that I checked chrome's location. I use only windows defender. I will check which one the client uses.

Comment: Still try x86..

Comment: Is chrome opeing after removing this line:-
`proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "web.whatsapp.com --new-window --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=\"Chrome Profile\"";`

Comment: @TusharChaurasia Nice Idea. Didn't try as I didn't had the source code handy at that time. Will give it  a try.

Comment: Nice, after this you can detect whether your application is opening Google Chrome, if no try launching Edge or Firefox because both are browsers and both can open `web.whatsapp.com`.

Comment: @TusharChaurasia Edge or Firefox is not an option. In next step, I connect to chrome using selenium and run some scripts. It would be a pretty hefty job to migrate.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about that.